# Sudden shut down of Windows 7 and blue screen appears

Tags: windows-7, crash

My warranty expired on September 30, 2017, and now I am facing this issue second time in the last 3 days. I am afraid that I might lose data or something else will happen. what issue is this → [image]

when I restarted this message appeared → [image]

Below is the complete message copy-paste →

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BlueScreen
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.2
  Locale ID:    1033

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode:   1000007e
  BCP1: FFFFFFFFC0000005
  BCP2: 0000000000000000
  BCP3: FFFFF880031BCDC8
  BCP4: FFFFF880031BC630
  OS Version:   6_1_7601
  Service Pack: 1_0
  Product:  768_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\110817-14664-01.dmp
  C:\Users\ntesla\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-38033-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Is this an alarm for some bigger chaos in the future or we can fix this somehow?

## UPDATE →

These are the software installed recently in descending order of the date → [image]

Comment: Have you run any hardware tests yet?

Comment: sir, can you please guide me how can I do this?

Comment: Please backup your data immediately if you are concerned about losing data. Next, specify what your make and model of computer is.

Comment: think center (By Lenovo → actually an IBM product)

Comment: Did you uninstall an anti-virus product or install new drivers lately? Googling 0x7e says it's due to anti-virus software removal, and 0x1000007e says it's video drivers.  Your screenshots show both errors, so I'm not sure which/if one could be the answer.

Comment: sir, I have updated the question. Please let me know if I have to provide something else.

Comment: [analyze the dmp with windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks)

Comment: Upload C:\Windows\Minidump\110817-14664-01.dmp to http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=Analyze and maybe update us with the results of that.

Comment: this is not opening in my machine → C:\Windows\Minidump\110817-14664-01.dmp

Comment: On  this website all the download options are available for Windows 10, but mine is windows 7 → https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/